# PHP Recursive function not returning value

Tags: php, function, recursion

Am I missing something? In trying to implement an algorithm I can't obtain a return value for a function. Originally trying to return an array I've encountered simple types won't work as well.

NOTE: This is a simplified version to illustrate the point. I'm aware that for the illustrated code one could use something like print_r(array_map(function($x){return $x+2;}, array(2, 4, 6, 8))); but this won't do in the full problem.

And for the question. I have the following code:

```
function recursive1($myArray, $accumulator){
  if(empty($myArray)){
    return $accumulator;
  } else {
    recursive1(array_slice($myArray, 1), $accumulator+1);
  }
}
$testArray = array(3, 5, 7, 9);
print("->".recursive1($testArray,10)."<-\n");
```

Getting nil as a result

```
(output)
-><-
```

Adding a little to see the internals I have

```
function recursive1($myArray, $accumulator){
  if(empty($myArray)){
    print("[".$accumulator."]\n");   // End result
    return $accumulator;
  } else {
    print("<".$accumulator.">");   // partial results
    recursive1(array_slice($myArray, 1), $accumulator+1);
  }
}
$testArray = array(3, 5, 7, 9);
print("->".recursive1($testArray,10)."<-\n");
```

I get that the function it's doing what it suppose to do but the return value is lost.

```
(output)
<10><11><12><13>[14]
-><-
```

So I should have

```
(output)
->14<-
```

By the way I'm using

```
>php -version
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2015 17:21:45)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0 Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

I've also tried to assign the value to a variable (outside the function) to no avail.

Any ideas? :-)

Comment: You should `return` the value in a recursive function. `return recursive1(array_slice($myArray, 1), $accumulator+1);`

Comment: Thanks to all. Back on business.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `return` statement and so your function returns nothing in the recursive branch. Change this line:

```
recursive1(array_slice($myArray, 1), $accumulator+1);
```

to

```
return recursive1(array_slice($myArray, 1), $accumulator+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have this:

```
else {
   print("<".$accumulator.">");   // partial results
   return recursive1(array_slice($myArray, 1), $accumulator+1);
}
```

Without the `return` statement, your final result is never returned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `return` to your recursive call:

```
return recursive1(array_slice($myArray, 1), $accumulator + 1);
```