# Funtion is not returning an array from 'else'

Tags: php, function, cakephp

I have following the recursive function:

```
public function get_referred_list_down($referral,$level){
    if($level>1){
        $users = $this->Invoice->User->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('User.referral'=>$referral),'fields'=>array('User.id','User.username')));
        $this->get_referred_list_down($users,$level-1);
    }else{
        $users = $this->Invoice->User->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('User.referral'=>$referral),'fields'=>array('User.id','User.username')));
    }
    return $users;
}
```

I am calling it as `$this->get_referred_list_down('DSTL00004',2);`

In `if` it returns the following array:

```
Array
(
    [9] => DSTL00005
    [10] => DSTL00006
    [11] => DSTL00007
    [12] => DSTL00008
    [13] => DSTL00009
)
```

I have passed it to the function again and it gives the following in `else`:

```
Array
(
    [14] => DSTL00010
    [15] => DSTL00011
    [16] => DSTL00012
    [17] => DSTL00013
)
```

But it returns the result of `if` rather than returning the result of `else`.

Comment: @Memor-X $referral variable is updated in else condition. so result is second array but return statement execute every time. I am unable to figure it out why its running every time.

Comment: your $users is changed every time you call the function again

Comment: @DionisL yes it is required behavior. But why return is called in if also?

Comment: actually in if there is call to function again so before going to return statement it calls the function recursively. In second loop it executes else statement and reach the return. But it is not working as expected

Comment: when you call it for "$this->get_referred_list_down('DSTL00004',2);" , first time  $level>1 will be true , and it will again call itself and this time $level>1 will be false so it will go on else

Comment: return will be called no matter your if is true or false :)

Comment: enable the debug mode in core.php and see what queries executing during the process.

Comment: why downvote? I think its genuine question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by adding a *return* before the recursive call to the function, so now the code looks like:

```
public function get_referred_list_down($referral, $level){
    if($level>1){
        $users = $this->Invoice->User->find('list', array('conditions' => array('User.referral' => $referral), 'fields' => array('User.id', 'User.username')));
        return $this->get_referred_list_down($users, $level - 1);
    }else{
        $users = $this->Invoice->User->find('list', array('conditions' => array('User.referral' => $referral), 'fields' => array('User.id', 'User.username')));
    }
    return $users;
}
```

Thanks to *[PHP Recursive function not returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736246/php-recursive-function-not-returning-value/35736286#35736286)*.